# How to include fonts in a Storybook build

Tags: css, fonts, styled-components, storybook

I have two custom font files in my storybook project, they are referenced like this:

```
import { TYPOGRAPHY } from './tokens';
import { css } from 'styled-components';

import SourceSansProRegular from '../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf';
import SourceSansProBold from '../assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf';

export const fontFaces = css`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Regular';
    src: url(${SourceSansProRegular}) format('ttf');
    font-weight: ${TYPOGRAPHY.WEIGHTS.REGULAR};
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Bold';
    src: url(${SourceSansProBold}) format('ttf');
    font-weight: ${TYPOGRAPHY.WEIGHTS.MEDIUM};
    font-style: normal;
  }
`;
```

My problem is that when I run `yarn build` (`BABEL_ENV=production babel src -d dist`), the resulting build does not include the font files. Does anyone know how to make it so the font files will be included in the dist folder?